# IE10 ::-ms-expand not working

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to implement a custom styled select element but having issues with IE10 and 11 where the native chevron is still visible. I've tried to implement the standard css to do this but to no avail:

```
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

I've even tried:

```
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none!important;
  visibility: hidden!important;
  opacity: 0!important;
}
```

On the select I have:

```
select {
  .......
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-overflow: '';
  .......
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, never did